# Is there a Latex symbol that combines \top and \bot?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'd like to have a symbol that is the exact overlap between `\top` and `\bot` so that it looks like the roman number "Ⅰ". I have searched a particular symbol, but I found nothing. And overlapping techniques in this and other forums are a little confusing.

Can someone help me?

Comment: One very simple alternative: a similar-looking character in Unicode, which you could use with unicode-math, is U+2336, APL functional symbol I-beam(⌶). The accepted answer is great, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following code implements `\bottop` that combines `\bot` and `\top` with respecting the current math style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\bottop}{%
  \mathpalette\@bottop{}%
}
\newcommand*{\@bottop}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \rlap{$#1\bot\m@th$}% put \bot to the right without moving the current point
  \top
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \bottop \scriptstyle \bottop \scriptscriptstyle \bottop \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

From http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf here is a possible implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\topbotatom#1{\hbox{\hbox to 0pt{$#1\bot$\hss}$#1\top$}}
\newcommand*{\topbot}{\mathrel{\mathchoice{\topbotatom\displaystyle}
        {\topbotatom\textstyle}
        {\topbotatom\scriptstyle}
        {\topbotatom\scriptscriptstyle}}}
\begin{document}
$\topbot$
\end{document}
```